# Passing js-objects hierarchy to Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model

```
  public class Foo{
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public DateTime Date {get; set;}
     public bool IsActive {get;set;}
     public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
  }

 public class Item{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Foo Foo {get;set;}
 }
```

And in my javascript I do that:

```
var items = new Array();
$("#itemsSelector").each(function () {
   items.push({Id: $(this).val(), Name: $(this).text() })
}

var id = $("#id").val();
var title = $("#title").val();
var date = $("#dateTimePicker").val();
var isActive = $("#msActive").val();

$.post("SaveFoo", {Id: id, Name:title, Date:date, IsActive: isActive, Items:items })
```

Action method signature looks like that:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SaveFoo(Foo foo) {
      // Now. here it passes correct Id, Name, Date and bool parameter
      // And even passes the correct number of Foo.Items
      // The only thing that bothers me -
      // all the properties of every Item is either null or zero!
 }
```

Why is that happening? What am I doing wrong? How to pass the objects array to the action? I've tried to use `jquery.serialize()` and `serializeArray()`and even `$.toDictionary()` method described [here](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html).

That's not helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried a JSON request? It works much better with complex properties and collections:

```
var items = new Array();
$('#itemsSelector').each(function () {
    items.push({ id: $(this).val(), name: $(this).text() });
}

var id = $('#id').val();
var title = $('#title').val();
var date = $('#dateTimePicker').val();
var isActive = $('#isActive').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'SaveFoo',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: id, 
        name: title, 
        date: date, 
        isActive: isActive, 
        items: items 
    }),
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

And if you need to support older browsers you might need to include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script so that the `JSON.stringify` function works.

Comment: and also if we look from academical point of view: what's the difference between your $.ajax and $.post. Only the contentType?

Comment: @Agzam, correct, I have updated my answer. You will need to include the `json2.js` script for legacy browsers that do not natively support the `JSON.stringify` method. And, yes, the only difference between the `$.post` and `$.ajax` is that the latter allows you to set the request content type header: `contentType`.

Comment: Thank you... you saved my day again! Someday I'll win a few billion dollars in a lottery, then I'll share as much money with you as your reputation score on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Agzam, as always it is pleasure for me when I can help fellow developers.